# Solution for using iTerm2 'shell integration' and screen (over ssh)

Tags: shell, iterm2

So when i ssh into a remote server i use 'screen -R myscreen' to prevent any running scripts/processes from being interrupted when the ssh connection disconnects, for whatever reason (bad wifi, etc).

However, when starting screen, iTerm2's shell integration doesn't work anymore.

Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 8):

fyi the solution i found is:

instead of 'screen' use 'tmux', by executing `tmux -CC` to open a tmux session (and using `tmux -CC attach` to re-attach after a disconnection.)
This is also described [here](https://gitlab.com/gnachman/iterm2/wikis/TmuxIntegration).

To make iTerm2 shell integration work in tmux, modify `~/.iterm2_shell_integration.bash` and remove this part of the first line:
`"$TERM" != screen`

So this

`if [[ "$TERM" != screen && "$ITERM_SHELL_INTEGRATION_INSTALLED" = "" && "$-" == *i* ]]; then`

becomes:

`if [[ "$ITERM_SHELL_INTEGRATION_INSTALLED" = "" && "$-" == *i* ]]; then`

Comment: TY! This fixed the problem that when I had shared bash histories, tmux and iterm I would get this error: "-bash: iterm2_preexec_invoke_cmd: command not found". I haven't done much testing but this is looking good right now...

Comment: But the session initiated by `tmux -CC` (instead of `tmux`) is more like `screen`, not `tmux` I found splitting panels hard to do...

Comment: In iTerm 3.2.9, the condition is `"$ITERM_ENABLE_SHELL_INTEGRATION_WITH_TMUX""$TERM" != screen`. So you can just set `ITERM_ENABLE_SHELL_INTEGRATION_WITH_TMUX=yes` before `source ~/.iterm2_shell_integration.bash` in your `.profile` now.

Comment: Any new solution for `screen` users? Thanks

Comment: this does not answer the question lol, "How do I make gnu screen work with Iterm?" >> "Use Tmux" huh that's not what I wanted to know

Answer (score 2):

You can use triggers to replicate almost all of the features of shell integration. See the **Triggers** section near the bottom of this document: https://www.iterm2.com/documentation-shell-integration.html